# data not getting fetched

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using this code for fetching data from database , I am getting `$data` fetched properly but i am not getting data properly in this variable `$seldata` why is it so

```
<?php
    include_once("includes/connection.php");
    include_once("includes/session.php");
    //echo $_SESSION['uid'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE eid = '{$_GET['id']}'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $data=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "data".$data;
    $sel_valsql="select * FROM selected_candidate WHERE eid = '{$_GET['id']}'";
    $sresult=mysql_query($sel_valsql);
    $seldata=mysql_fetch_array($sresult);
    echo "seledata".$seldata;       
?>
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include_once("includes/connection.php");
include_once("includes/session.php");
//echo $_SESSION['uid'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE eid = '".$_GET['id']."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$data=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "data".$data;
$sel_valsql="select * FROM selected_candidate WHERE eid = '".$_GET['id']."'";
$sresult=mysql_query($sel_valsql);
$seldata=mysql_fetch_array($sresult);
echo "seledata".$seldata;       
?>
```

Note: mysql_fetch_array() returns an array of results so you need to do print_r($seldata) in order to view the results.

Comment: I tried `print_r($seldata)`,but it is not showing me any result,but when i use `print_r($data)` i get the result properly fetched

Comment: Try doing mysql_num_rows($sresult) and see if it gives any number greater than 0. If not then probably there is no matching record in the database.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE eid = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote form the where condition i.e.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE eid = {$_GET['id']}";
```

or do like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE eid = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
```